# Is there a way to receive key input to an out-focus form?

Tags: c#, forms, focus

I was wondering if it is possible to receive key input to a form that is out of focus. For example, I have my C# form to be top-most of all windows; I want to get all the keys I type on other applications like for example browser to kinda get a history of all the keys I typed while my computer was on.?

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This sort of question has been raised before, with concerns around keyloggers raised

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a [global keyboard hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261561/what-is-involve-in-creating-a-music-player-in-net/2261614#2261614) although be advised that this is not necessarily considered a good practice, and might cause issues with Anti-virus software.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here to see my answer in this keyboard hooking business [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259430/how-to-get-keyboard-input-while-running-in-vmware-virtual-machine/2259719#2259719)...in the link this OP was trying to find out how to hook the keyboard when running a VMWare session...In my answer I gave a couple of links pointing to the direction of CodeProject's articles on keyboard hooking.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.